# Cross Compiling Code with boost giving compile errors

Tags: c++11, boost, android-ndk

{`Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, arm-g++ compiler 4.9` one that comes with google's ndk r10c}

(I've made a stand-alone toolchain for platform android-14 and `--sysroot` point to that. Also flag `-march=armv7-a` is passed to the compiler)

on using arm cross-compiler for compiling boost I get the following error in `socket_ops.ipp`:

`<1>` for all function (templates) of this type:

```
template <typename SockLenType>
inline int call_getsockname(SockLenType msghdr::*, 
    socket_type s, socket_addr_type* addr, std::size_t* addrlen) 
{ 
  SockLenType tmp_addrlen = (SockLenType)*addrlen; 
  int result = ::getsockname(s, addr, &tmp_addrlen); 
  *addrlen = (std::size_t)tmp_addrlen; 
  return result; 
} 

/some-path/thirdparty/boost/boost_1_55_0_Android/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:1639: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'socklen_t* {aka unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive] 
   int result = ::getsockname(s, addr, &tmp_addrlen); 


                                              ^
```

On changing the line to:

```
int result = ::getsockname(s, addr, (socklen_t*)tmp_addrlen);
```

it compiles fine ofcourse but i don't know if this is what is to be done.

`<2>` And in `mapped_region.hpp`:

```
/some-path/thirdparty/boost/boost_1_55_0_Android/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp:49: error: sys/shm.h: No such file or directory 
 #      include <sys/shm.h>      //System V shared memory...
                                                        ^
```

and points to:

```
#    if defined(BOOST_INTERPROCESS_XSI_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS) 
#      include <sys/shm.h>      //System V shared memory... 
#    endif
```

in that file.

Here are the flags in my user-config.jam file:

```
using gcc : android 
: 
@AndroidNDKSrcDir@/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ 
: 
<archiver>@AndroidNDKSrcDir@/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar 
<compileflags>-fexceptions 
<compileflags>-frtti 
<compileflags>-fPIC 
<compileflags>-std=c++11 
<compileflags>-ffunction-sections 
<compileflags>-funwind-tables 
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5__ 
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ 
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ 
<compileflags>-D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ 
<compileflags>-Wno-psabi 
<compileflags>-march=armv5te 
<compileflags>-mtune=xscale 
<compileflags>-msoft-float 
<compileflags>-mthumb 
<compileflags>-Os 
<compileflags>-fomit-frame-pointer 
<compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing 
<compileflags>-finline-limit=64 
<compileflags>-I@AndroidNDKSrcDir@/include/c++/4.9 
<compileflags>-Wa,--noexecstack 
<compileflags>-DANDROID 
<compileflags>-D__ANDROID__ 
<compileflags>-DNDEBUG 
<compileflags>-O2 
<compileflags>-g 
<compileflags>-I@AndroidNDKSrcDir@/sysroot/usr/include 
<architecture>arm 
<compileflags>-fvisibility=hidden 
<compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden 
<compileflags>-fdata-sections 
<cxxflags>-D__arm__ 
<cxxflags>-D_REENTRANT 
<cxxflags>-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS 
;
```

What is the way forward for those two errors - **<1>** and **<2>** above ? Is boost (asio etc) Android ready with c++11 features ?

Comment: For `<1>`, whoever is calling `call_getsockname` is passing a data member pointer of type `int` for the first argument, when it should be of type `unsigned`. Why is this even a template parameter? It always needs to be `unsigned` (or, more accurately, `socklen_t`)... Or maybe you meant `socklen_t tmp_addrlen = (socklen_t)*addrlen;` instead, so that any integral type could be passed?

Comment: How exactly does _your_ code call `call_getsockname()` function?

Comment: @ildjarn `Why is this even a template parameter?` The function belongs to boost itself, i have no idea why it would be templated.

Comment: @AlexCohn: It's a boost impl file. If you see the function the is right below it ie., `getsockname`, it passes it `&msghdr::msg_namelen` which is `int*`. So it is boost doing it. Edit: And that (`getsockname`) is not a function template, so mere inclusion of the header causes the compile error.

Comment: In **android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/socket.h** from **ndk-r10c** we find `typedef int socklen_t;`. Therefore, you either don't `#include` the correct `<sys/socket.h>`, or you have somewhere a `#define` that overrides it. ***Update***: for _android-21_, `socklen_t` may be defined in `<sys/types.h>` as **unsigned**.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Hmm. i see, due to lack of support of complete c++11, I'm using crystax ndk and for me socklen_t comes finally from machine/_types.h. Looking at android 21 on r10c from google I see that `int` was more sort of a historical mistake as written in the comment in types.h. Crystax guys seem to have corrected that and is causing error. Let me get in touch with them because  I guess `linux/socket.h -> msghdr::msg_namelen` (which is `int` right now) must be of the same type as `socklen_t`, no? That is what is causing the problem. In the meantime do you have anything for <2>

Comment: I guess that you can find many ways to work around this incompatibility for msghdr::msg_namelen. No, I have nothing for `<2>`. What part of C++11 are you missing with **gnustl** on **r10c**?

Comment: @AlexCohn: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902989/cross-compiling-for-arm-using-crystax-ndk

Comment: @AlexCohn oh btw you are in the comments there :) just noticed.

Comment: Thanks; I missed [_crystax_](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104932/crystax)' comments about `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99`. I don't know how bad this is, maybe you can simply `#define` it.

Answer (score 0):

**<1>** you have incompatible `<sys/socket.h>` and `<socket_ops.ipp>` - for whatever reason. The "fix" that you suggested would compile, but crash at runtime. Here is the easiest fix that will work for you:

```
int tmp_addrlen = (int)*addrlen; 
int result = ::getsockname(s, addr, &tmp_addrlen);
```

On Android, which is [LP64](http://community.arm.com/thread/6598), such cast is not safe, but for goodness sake, nobody is going to use addrlen of more than 2^32.