# How to cross-compile gperftools for android using crystax-NDK & autotools?

Tags: android, android-ndk, autotools

My final goal is to be able to profile native code (C++) in android environments using gperftools.

My environment/Tools:

- ubuntu 14.04
- crystax-ndk-10.2.1
- gcc-4.8.4
- gperftools-2.4

(1)
I followed through this to make a standalone toolchain for later use:
[Cross compiling for arm using crystax NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902989/cross-compiling-for-arm-using-crystax-ndk)

command:

```
./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --system=linux-x86_64 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 --platform=android-8 --install-dir=$HOME/my-android-toolchain
```

(2)
Thankfully, I found a script that will simplify the ./configure work:
https://gist.github.com/nddrylliog/4688209

and just modified it a bit (put in gperftools-2.4 folder):

```
#!/bin/sh

export DEV_PREFIX=$HOME

export ANDROID_NDK=${DEV_PREFIX}/crystax-ndk-10.2.1/

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi

export ANDROID_PREFIX=$HOME/my-android-toolchain

export SYSROOT=${ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-8/arch-arm

export CROSS_PATH=${ANDROID_PREFIX}/bin/${CROSS_COMPILE}

export CPP=${CROSS_PATH}-cpp
export AR=${CROSS_PATH}-ar
export AS=${CROSS_PATH}-as
export NM=${CROSS_PATH}-nm
export CC=${CROSS_PATH}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_PATH}-g++
export LD=${CROSS_PATH}-ld
export RANLIB=${CROSS_PATH}-ranlib

# export PREFIX=${DEV_PREFIX}/android/prefix

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig

export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} --sysroot=${SYSROOT} -I${SYSROOT}/usr/include -I${ANDROID_PREFIX}/include -I${DEV_PREFIX}/android/bionic"
export CPPFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L${SYSROOT}/usr/lib -L${ANDROID_PREFIX}/lib"

./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE} --with-sysroot=${SYSROOT} "$@"
```

(3)
And then I actually do the `./configure` and make install:

I put this script in gperftools-2.4 folder and run it:

```
cd gperftools-2.4
./android_configure.sh --enable-frame-pointers --prefix=$(pwd)
sudo make && make install
cd ..
```

Result:
The above gives me this error:

```
src/static_vars.cc: In function 'void tcmalloc::SetupAtForkLocksHandler()':
src/static_vars.cc:119:39: error: 'pthread_atfork' was not declared in this scope
                  CentralCacheUnlockAll); // child calls after fork
```

I would appreciate if anyone could leave me some advice on this.

Extra:
I know there is a [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler) but since I use CMake for the cross-compilation and I'm not quite sure how to mess with the Android.mk so at the moment I will try to use gperftools which works fine in linux build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `pthread_atfork` appeared in Android libc (Bionic) only from Android 5.0. In CrystaX NDK, not all API are replaced by libcrystax, in particular, all pthread_xxx API reside in libc. So the only way as of now to do what you want is either use android-21 as minimal platform, or modify gperftools sources, avoiding usage of `pthread_atfork`.

BTW, we're working on moving all pthread_xxx API into libcrystax, so I expect all such API will be available soon even for earlier Android versions.